# Pytrends: How to specify a word as a Topic instead of a Search Term?

Tags: python, google-trends

I'm trying to extract query index from Google Trends using pytrends:

```
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['holiday'], timeframe='all', geo='US')
```

When using the Google Trends dashboard, we can specify whether a word (e.g. Holiday) is a Topic or a Search Term.

How can I do this using pytrends? The mid for the topic Holiday is %2Fm%2F03gkl . Can this be used in some way in the “kw_list” above so that the query index is for the Topic?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pytrends to retrieve topic level trends as well, though it's not very straight forward. Using `topic_id` as a parameter instead of the `topic_name` will do the job.

For example in your case,

- topic_id of the term "Holiday" is `/m/03gkl`

```
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list=["/m/03gkl"], cat=0, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='', gprop='')

pytrends.interest_over_time()
```

Similarly, you can also combine a regular search term along with a another topic area.

For example, A comparison between `GoPro` as a search term and `Holiday` as a topic will look like this.

```
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list=["/m/03gkl","GoPro"], cat=0, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='', gprop='')

pytrends.interest_over_time()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's very helpful.

Comment: I am trying to use this approach and its not really working. The topic I am using is  /g/11c0vm752r  It returns results that are extremely small, between 0 and 2, while in Gtrends I saw data around 80